# Does of order data points in excel influence the Regression results in Excel

Tags: excel, regression

I tried to do a regression analysis with some 91 data points. When I did the regression analysis initially, I got R value as 0.366733. Later I sorted the datapoints from smallest to largest and then did the regression analysis. My new R value is 0.04323. Does the order in which the original data points are arranged influence the regression analysis

Comment: Q Off topic here

Comment: If you sort in the other direction and try again, what happens?

Answer (score 2):

The ordering of *paired* datapoints does not matter in regression

For example:

```
5   9
6   1
3   7
9   5
6   4
```

Gives a correlation (which is the same as standardized regression) of `-0.37`

If I reorder the entire data based on column 1 values:

```
3   7
5   9
6   1
6   4
9   5
```

I get the same correlation of `-0.37`. Notice that the pairs are still aligned, i.e. both columns are being sorted together

But in Excel its very easy to get into a situation like the following, where you're sorting by only a single column. Meaning one column will be the ordered, but the pair alignment is broken because the second column doesnt change:

```
3   9
5   1
6   7
6   5
9   4
```

Now I get a correlation of `-0.41`. The pairs of data are no longer aligned and effectively makes this a completely different dataset than before

Bottom line: when youre sorting in Excel make sure you've selected all of your data for the sort and not just a single column